# Does URLSession.shared.downloadTask create a multithreaded downloading session?

Tags: swift, networking, urlsession

The title says everything but in other words are `URLSession` download tasks single threaded or multithreaded (like IDM and other download manager apps)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both. URLSession can create parallel tasks in separate threads, pipelined tasks over HTTP or HTTP/2 in a single thread, or entirely out-of-process requests (so while there is another "thread" that's because it's in a completely different process). What it actually does depends on the requests you make, the options you put on those requests, and what features the server supports.

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to observe the process of each thread `URLSession` creates ?

Comment: Not as it creates it without sticking a debugger on it and following through the assembly (if you want to do that, I recommend Hopper as a well-priced disassembler and debugger). You can generally see them in the stack trace in Xcode, or Instruments. Remember that part of URLSession is handled with GCD, and queues and sources do not map 1:1 with threads. Don't assume there is a specific thread handling a specific request. It's also changed quite a bit over the years (out-of-process is relatively new).

Comment: Thank you so much, but I meant the code way for the app itself not for debugging, something like a delegate or a closure or an observable field

Comment: Definitely not. How URLSession manages its own threads, queues, sources, and connections are internal implementation details. Interesting for exploration, but you'd never rely on them. I've used reverse engineering on the URL loading system to explore performance improvements (particularly how many simultaneous connections it's willing to make; at the time I was exploring I believe it was 6), but I can't imagine anything you would want to make use of in "normal" code.

Comment: Thank you so much, Helped me a lot